# To unlock a pdf file with Ghostscript in windows

Tags: windows, pdf, ghostscript

I need to unlock copy content restrictions (to copy&paste) from pdf files.

In linux I've used ghostscript and works fine.  But at work we have win7.

I've tried this with ghostscript for win, gswin32c.exe:

```
gswin32c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sFONTPATH=%windir%/fonts;xfonts;. -sPDFPassword= -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPassThroughJPEGImages=true -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf INPUT.pdf
```

The console output is:

```
    **** Warning: File has a corrupted %%EOF marker, or garbage after %%EOF.
WARNING: /Unicode /Decoding is not accesible but it is useful for generating ToUnicode CMap.
Procesing pages 1 throught 1.
Page 1
```

The pdf input file has 4 pages, and it doesn't generate the output.pdf file.

Then I've renamed de input file from `INPUT.pdf` to `INPUT.ps` and proceded in the same way, but it doesn't generate any output file neither. The output console is:

```
   **** Warning: File has a corrupted %%EOF marker, or garbage after %%EOF.
WARNING: /Unicode /Decoding resource is not accessible but it is useful for gene
rating ToUnicode CMap.
Processing pages 1 through 4.
Page 1
Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from n019003l.pfb... 2347400 998541 2841520 1526888
 3 done.
Loading NimbusSanL-Bold font from n019004l.pfb... 2404280 1086944 2841520 153288
3 3 done.
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by:
   **** >>>> null <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

My Ghostscript version is 8.56.

The purpose of doing with Ghostscript is I need to extract the content text from the pdf with the `PDFminer` Python library.

Comment: Ghostscript 8.56 is rather old (2007). You might want to try the latest version which is currently [9.14](http://www.ghostscript.com/GPL_Ghostscript_9.14.html).

Comment: @RolandSmith It's that the issue?

Comment: Could very well be. What is the Ghostscript version that you've used on Linux?

Comment: @RolandSmith 9.10 in lubuntu VM

Comment: @RolandSmith I already tried with 9.14 version.  It doesn't throws the warning, but the output.pdf isn't generated.  Any suggestion?

Comment: It could be that the ghostscript used in lubuntu is patched to ignore PDF restrictions.